# Add value to props when no matches found with React Bootstrap Typeahead

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap-typeahead

With React Bootstrap Typeahead, if there is no record found and display "no matches found", is it possible I can add that value to the selected props when I click enter?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `allowNew` prop to add arbitrary items to the selections:

```
<Typeahead
  allowNew
  options={[...]}
  selected={[...]}
/>
```

When users enter a string that isn't found in the set of options, they'll be presented with a menu option giving them the ability to add the text they've entered as a selection:

[image]

Here's a working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/rbt-custom-selections-18piu

Answer (score 0):

Use the props like
emptyLabel="YOUR_CUSTOM_TEXT"